# how to respond back to main thread?

Tags: android, timer

am creating a simple application. Application has to display dialog box, run a timer at the background. When the timer elapses, beep should be played. however if the dialog box is clicked before timer, the timer should be cancelled. I am posting what I have done so far, with this code, am getting the beep first and then dialog box, how to say to main thread that the timer has finished?

public class main extends Activity 
{

```
static final int DIALOG_ADDPLAYERS = 0;

Thread backgroundThread;
TextView myText;
myCounter counter;
MediaPlayer mp;

Handler handler = new Handler(){

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
    {
            playAudio();
    }

};

 protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        switch(id)
        {
        case 0:

                builder.setTitle("Restart Game");
                builder.setMessage("Are you sure to restart the game?");
                builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {
                        counter.cancel();
                    }});
                builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {
                        counter.cancel();   
                    }   
                });


            break;


        default:
        }
        return builder.create();    
    }

void playAudio()
{
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.beep);
    mp.setLooping(false);
    mp.start();
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener(){
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0)
        {
            finish();
        }
    });
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener(){
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0)
        {
            finish();
        }});

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mp!=null)
    {
        mp.release();
        mp=null;
    }
}



/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    myText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytext);

    //Toast.makeText(this, "onCreate()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
    showDialog(0);
    startMyTimer();
}




protected void startMyTimer() 
{    
    counter = new myCounter((long)10000,(long)1000);
    backgroundThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() 
        {       
                try 
                {
                    //Thread.sleep(10000);


                    counter.startTimer();

                } 
                catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


        }

    });
    backgroundThread.start();
}
```

}

This is my MyCounter class:

```
package com.androidbook.bgthread;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;

public class myCounter extends CountDownTimer 
{
    public myCounter(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) 
    {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() 
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
    {


    }

    public void startTimer()
    {
        start();
    }   

}
```

Is this the right way to do it? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Handler: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html. This lets you send a message to the main thread from any other thread.

A helpful reference is at https://web.archive.org/web/20200810154212/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/using-handler-in-android.html

Comment: I dont have to use countdown timer explicitly? Alsi I have to make beep play when the time is up. how do I do that?

Comment: You can use the countdown timer: nothing particularly wrong with it. As far as a beep goes not sure: haven't ever tried that.